# Activate Javascript function after clicking on Rails form_for select field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, onclick

I have a form with 3 input fields, strokes, putts, and GIR:

```
<%= form_for(@played_hole) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :hole_par, value: @hole.par %>

  <%= f.label :strokes, "How many strokes?" %>
  <%= f.select(:strokes, options_for_select(generate_strokes_array(@hole.par), selected: @hole.par)) %>

  <%= f.label :putts, "How many putts?" %>
  <%= f.select :putts, options_for_select(generate_putts_array(5), selected: 1), onclick: calculateGIR() %>    

  <%= f.label :GIR, "Green in Regulation?" %>
  <%= f.select(:GIR, [['Yes', 1], ['No', 0]]) %>

  <%= f.submit "Next Hole", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>

<% end %>
```

My goal is to automatically select the 3rd field (:GIR) once the user clicks on the second input, putts.  For example, if the hole is a par 4 and they selected 5 in the :strokes field and 2 in the :putts field, then I would know that they didn't get a Green In Regulation.  So, I'd like to automatically switch the :GIR select to 'No'.

I'm currently having trouble just getting an onclick() event registered.  I've added `onclick: calculateGIR()` to the :putts select field but I'm getting this error in my PlayedHole#new view: `undefined method calculateGIR' for #<#<Class:0xb5a684c4>:0xb591eac8>`

I've added this to the javascript/played_holes.js file: `function calculateGIR() { alert("calculating GIR"); }` but obviously it's not being picked up.

Basically, I could use some help calling javascript (or jQuery) functions within a view.  And then once I get that setup I'd like to figure out how to pull the selected value from :strokes and :putts to calculate the GIR.

For those curious, a GIR means you were on the green in 2 (or less) strokes than the par for the hole.  i.e. Par 3 - 1 stroke, Par 4 - 2 strokes, Par 5 - 3 (or less) strokes.

And I'm running Rails 3.2, in case you're curious.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `<%= f.select :putts, options_for_select(generate_putts_array(5), selected: 1), onclick: 'calculateGIR()' %>`, put the `calculateGIR()` in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `calculateGIR()` in quotes:

```
<%= f.select :putts, options_for_select(generate_putts_array(5), selected: 1), onclick: "calculateGIR()" %>
```

The `onclick` HTML attribute should be a a string of JavaScript code that will be executed on click. Instead, you are trying to call a Ruby method, `calculateGIR`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to my comment in your question:

> Try: `<%= f.select :putts, options_for_select(generate_putts_array(5),
>   selected: 1), onclick: 'calculateGIR()' %>`, put `calculateGIR()` in
>   quotes.

It's better not to place javascript into your HTML as you've shown.  [Unobstrusive](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript) way to do this would be to assign an `id` to the `select` element and apply `calculateGIR` logic in the change event.

Something like following is better:

In your view:

```
<%= f.select :putts, options_for_select(generate_putts_array(5), selected: 1), {}, id: 'putts' %>
```

In your `javascript/played_holes.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#putts').on('change', function() {
     // Place definition of calculateGIR() here.
  });
});
```